# Can I get trapped in my own Demiplane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I've been looking at the 8th-level spell *Demiplane*:

> When the spell ends, the door disappears, and any creatures or objects inside the demiplane remain trapped there, as the door also disappears from the other side. Each time you cast this spell, you can create a new demiplane, or have the shadowy door connect to a demiplane you created with a previous casting of this
>   spell.

This looks very useful as a portable shelter, or as a vault or prison for items or creatures the party needs to contain. I just have one question about the exact mechanics of the doorway.

If someone is inside the demiplane when the door closes, it explicitly says that they're stuck there. (It doesn't say that they can't use teleport or plane shift, but that's a separate question.) What it doesn't say is whether *I* get stuck. Can you open the door back to your home plane if you're inside?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Yes, you can trap yourself.

The destination of *Demiplane* is always a demiplane, either newly-created or preexisting and familiar to you.  By recasting the spell you could return to any demiplane familiar to you, but not to a non-demiplane such as the Prime Material.

If you don't have an appropriate spell such as *Plane Shift*, you will be trapped.

Comment: I don't see anything prohibiting you from opening a door from a demiplane back to the same demiplane, other than the risk that a deranged modron demigod will promise you cake.

Comment: That's exactly how I read it. Cool, good to know. I guess you could always find someone to install a gate or teleportation circle in a demiplane, and then if you get trapped, you can cast the spell again to get to *that* demiplane, and then gate home.

Comment: @Sebkha yes, you can make a portal from the demiplane into itself. And the modron gods won't give you cake. You either have Magnificent Mansion or starve.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I believe the list of spells that can get you out of that pickle are: Banishment, Gate, and Plane Shift.  Banishment requires you to fail a save, but it's fairly low level in comparison to the others, so you have many tries (not many high CHA wizards anyway =).  Only trouble is you don't control where you reappear, but that might still be better than staying stuck.

Comment: To add to @BlivetWidget's list, I see that _Word of Recall_ doesn't have the standard "must be on the same plane of existence" caveat that most other teleportation spells include to prohibit extraplanar travel. Assuming preparation was made, this spell should be able to get you out of a demiplane.